# Unknown display font detected on ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, malware

I just suddenly started seeing what is in the screenshot below and I don't know how it came to be. I don't even know if it is a virus or so. Surfed the internet for solutions but found none.

[image]

How can I resolve it?

Comment: To my eyes, that looks more like a font issue than a language issue. Did you change the system fonts, perhaps?

Comment: I have been able to trace the problem. Something tampered with my fonts, I don't what it is. What I did was to search for fonts in the dock. I then selected the tweak app. From there, I was able to locate fonts and change them back to default.@KGIII

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I was reasonably confident that it was a font issue and not a language issue.